# How can I display base64 image in html .net core?

Tags: html, .net

**EmailConfirmation.html**
I changed the png image to base64, but it dosn't work!!! the image cannot be displayed.

```
  <td width="100%" align="right" style="border-bottom: #695747 1px solid; color: #333333; font-size: 18px; vertical-align:bottom; text-align:left; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 15px;">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,code_base64" />
</td>
```

I added this methode which **SendEmailAsync()**, **BuildEmailBody()** : template
There is any solution to this issue...

```
public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message, string template)
        {
            var strMessageBody = BuildEmailBody(message, template, subject);

            if (_sendGridOptions.IsDefault)
            {
                _functionalSvc.SendEmailBySendGridAsync(_sendGridOptions.SendGridKey, _sendGridOptions.FromEmail, _sendGridOptions.FromFullName, subject, strMessageBody, email).Wait();
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strMessageBody))
            {
_functionalSvc.SendEmailByGmailAsync(_smtpOptions.FromEmail,
                    _smtpOptions.FromFullName,
                    subject,
                    strMessageBody,
                    email,
                    email,
                    _smtpOptions.SmtpUserName,
                    _smtpOptions.SmtpPassword,
                    _smtpOptions.SmtpHost,
                    _smtpOptions.SmtpPort,
                    _smtpOptions.SmtpSsl).Wait();
               
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        private string BuildEmailBody(string message, string templateName, string subject)
        {
            var strMessage = "";

            try
            {
                var strTemplateFilePath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "/EmailTemplates/" + templateName;
                var reader = new StreamReader(strTemplateFilePath);
                strMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("An error occurred while seeding the database  {Error} {StackTrace} {InnerException} {Source}",
                    ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException, ex.Source);
            }

            strMessage = strMessage.Replace("[[[Title]]]", string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject) ? "Notification => aimc.com" : subject);
            strMessage = strMessage.Replace("[[[message]]]", message);
            return strMessage;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `code_base64`? Is it supposed to be a string variable?

Comment: Image converted to base64, yes string

Comment: Is this inside a razor view (cshtml)? If so you will need to wrap the variable with a `@Html.Raw(code_base64)` to avoid any characters from potentially being escaped.

Comment: The issue is to display this image in a emailMessage, I updated the code... SignIn confirmation (Angular + .Net Core)

Comment: Is `code_base64` just a placeholder for the actual base64 encoded image in the template?

Comment: Yes this is encoded inage